# How to Calculate relative week diff in excel. If I Have Year and week in one column

Tags: excel

I am trying create a data set and finding it difficult to do it manually. I just wanted to know if there is way we can do it automatically in Excel.

I am trying to calculate the week difference with reference current year & calendar week.
Below is the formula used to calculate current year & calendar week
=YEAR(TODAY())&WEEKNUM(NOW()) Result would be 201840

I am expecting the weekdiff calculation as shown below. Any help in this regard would be deeply appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Why are you using `DATE()` to determine the year and `NOW()` to determine the week number?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert Year/Week to the overall week since 0 A.D. and then subtract.  This may need some adjustment for Leap years.

```
=(YEAR(TODAY()) * 52) + WEEKNUM(NOW())  - (VALUE(LEFT(A2,4))* 52) -   VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))
```